# Crack between brick backed plaster and plasterboard backed plaster

Tags: drywall, brick, plaster, crack

I have a room where there is a large crack running from floor to ceiling along one of the walls. To the left of the crack it sounds solid and appears to be plastered onto the side of the chimney, to the right it sounds hollow and I believe it a stud wall with plasterboard.

[image: Crack from floor to ceiling]
[image: Plaster on brick chimney]
[image: Plaster on plasterboard]

Both sides seem very solid with no detectable movement in them. What is the best way to repair this crack?

Comment: if you're about to move anyway, spackle and can foam would let you repaint it. If keeping, i would have a pro take a look at it to make sure you're not band-aiding something serious.